# Стиль для активной ссылки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть табы на чистом CSS, но как сделать чтоб первая ссылка была активной, имела собственный стиль, и при перекликованнии табов, ссылки тоже сватали активные. Пробую с `:active`, `:focus` но данный метод работает только во время нажатия на таб. С использованием Js это, конечно,  легко сделать, но можно ли без JS?

```css
.target:not(:target),
:target ~ .target.default-target {
  display: none;
}
.target:target,
.target.default-target {
  display: block;
}

a:active, a:focus{
  background-color: #7B7B7B;
  padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#id1">Блок 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#id2">Блок 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#id3">Блок 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#id4">Блок 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="target" id="id2">
  <p>Sed lobortis placerat elit tincidunt tempor. Nam dignissim euismod quam nec tempor. Sed tortor lorem, ultricies a auctor nec, auctor ut neque. Aenean varius, urna eget adipiscing feugiat, nunc ligula molestie massa, id accumsan turpis metus ac ante.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
</div>

<div class="target" id="id3">
  <p>Pellentesque quis tortor vitae elit cursus vulputate et vel dui. Nunc commodo pretium arcu in ultricies. Nunc vel velit enim, et tincidunt leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
</div>

<div class="target" id="id4">
  <p>Quisque eget tempor sapien. Cras convallis tempor orci pulvinar scelerisque. Nullam et erat eu nibh sollicitudin congue sit amet id diam. Sed in lectus ut augue euismod porta. Quisque non lacus odio. Nunc ornare adipiscing egestas.</p>
</div>

<div class="target default-target" id="id1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempus, felis at varius eleifend, neque orci porta magna, consequat aliquam ligula velit quis erat. Aenean porttitor pellentesque risus, eu tincidunt ipsum blandit in.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы знаете я недавно тщательно исследовал, я не увидел красивое, чистое решение на CSS.

Comment: прав @VadimOvchinnikov, вот тут есть примеры табов, некоторые становятся активными: https://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/ но честно говоря для динамической вёрстки они не подойдут, да и выглядят некрасиво в плане реализации

Comment: Еще думал место ссылок использовать input type radio + label + :checked, но данный подход тоже не красивый , так что пару строк js все таки придется использовать.

Comment: @Shperung, input type radio + label + :checked - не нужна не единая строка js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
/* Очищаем форматирование общего блока, чтоб float не вилял на
размещенные элементы после табов */
#tabs::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

/* Предотвращаем прокрутку к tab-content при нажатии на ссылку */
.tab-switch {
  position: fixed;
}

.tab-link {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Блок с содержимым изначально сокрытый и имеет параметр float:right
для смещения под .tab-link. Если убрать float или заменить его на flex,
.tab-link будет смещаться при переключении. Тут же указано наследование
стиля при нажатии на ссылку, чтоб спрятать изначально активный блок.
Если класс .active разместить в начале кода, то при нажатии на ссылку
не будет срабатывать наследование между родственными селекторами, так
как ссылка в коде будет после данного блока. */
.tab-content,
.tab-switch:target ~ .tab-content.active {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
/* Включаем сокрытый блок используя target и id прописанный в href */
.tab-switch:target + .tab-link + .tab-content,
.tab-content.active{
  display: block;
}

#tabs {
  font-size: 0;
}

/* Описание стиля кнопок переключения табов и аналогичная работа с
оформлением этих кнопок как в переключение скрытых блоков */
.tab-link,
:target ~ .tab-link.active {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
}
.tab-link:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.tab-switch:target + .tab-link,
.tab-link.active {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}

/* Это просто внешний вид */
.tab-content {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.tab-content p {
  line-height: 1.65;
}
.tab-content ul, .tab-content ol {
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
.tab-content ul > li, .tab-content ol > li {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <span id="tab-1" class="tab-switch"></span>
    <a href="#tab-1" class="tab-link">Таб 1</a>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <h2>Таб 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias amet commodi cupiditate molestias laboriosam sit! Delectus magni esse magnam libero laboriosam aspernatur voluptates, natus aliquid sed doloremque architecto provident, impedit saepe. Mollitia eum qui, quae laboriosam, magni aut similique asperiores error dicta totam ad, deserunt nemo repudiandae maxime, expedita. Id, numquam, laboriosam. Voluptatibus, saepe! Eligendi assumenda ullam modi explicabo voluptas qui veniam repellat ipsam similique dolore, mollitia quam dolores quae cumque neque officia. Laudantium, ratione sint quo molestiae sapiente dolores, doloremque modi illo quia tempora asperiores ullam perspiciatis fuga quasi maxime nesciunt ab suscipit harum quam. Eligendi dicta suscipit dolorum.</p>
    </div>

    <span id="tab-2" class="tab-switch"></span>
    <a href="#tab-2" class="tab-link">Таб 2</a>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <h2>Таб 2</h2>
        <ul>
           <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
           <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
           <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <span id="tab-3" class="tab-switch"></span>
    <a href="#tab-3" class="tab-link active">Таб 3</a>
    <div class="tab-content active">
        <h2>Таб 3</h2>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Код красивый. Принцип тот же. Оформление допилите. Единственный минус - активный блок может быть только в конце из-за наследования класса к которому привязка идет для сокрытия начального блока. Можете попробовать поиграться с float-ом или со структурой в целом, думаю этот момент можно добить.

Для понимания основных принципов потребуется почитать про:

- [Соседние селекторы](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/adjacent)
- [Родственные селекторы](http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/sibling)
- [Псевдокласс :target](http://htmlbook.ru/css/target)
- [Другие стили](http://htmlbook.ru/css)

Comment: остаётся  в адресной строке id якоря , это конечно хорошее решение но из за адресной строки косяк

Comment: Отличный вариант, поигрался с flex-direction: row-reverse; и первый активный теперь   "Таб 1"

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev Отличный ответ. А сможете 1. добавить комментарии по коду и объяснить принципы? 2. Заменить `float` на flexbox?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Спасибо. Добавил комментарии в код. Рассказчик из меня никудышный, если что-то не понятно, спрашивайте. Смысла заменять на flex не вижу, да и не получится скорее всего (Просто уберите float и поймете какую функцию он играет при построении всей конструкции). На досуге еще подумаю, как сместить активный таб в начало списка.

Comment: @Shperung Спасибо. Оно то так, только все пункты нужно будет в обратном порядке формировать, впрочем, это не большая проблема. Пока это единственный вариант реализации со смещением активного блока влево. Или мелкий скрипт выбирающий нужное значение при загрузке страницы. Хотя, от скрипта мы все же пытались избавиться.

Comment: Еще один плюс можно сделать это  класс active не использовать, а в css  обращаться как :nth-last-of-type(1). Так как  табы будут добавляться динамически .

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью `input radio`:

```css
.target {
  display: none;
}
input#t1:checked ~ .target#id1 {display: block;}
input#t2:checked ~ .target#id2 {display: block;}
input#t3:checked ~ .target#id3 {display: block;}
input#t4:checked ~ .target#id4 {display: block;}

input[type="radio"] {display:none;}

input#t1:checked ~ ul li label[for="t1"],
input#t2:checked ~ ul li label[for="t2"],
input#t3:checked ~ ul li label[for="t3"],
input#t4:checked ~ ul li label[for="t4"],
label:active {
  background-color: #7B7B7B;
  padding:3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="tab" id="t1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="tab" id="t2">
<input type="radio" name="tab" id="t3">
<input type="radio" name="tab" id="t4">
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="t1">Блок 1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="t2">Блок 2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="t3">Блок 3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="t4">Блок 4</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="target" id="id2">
  <p>Sed lobortis placerat elit tincidunt tempor. Nam dignissim euismod quam nec tempor. Sed tortor lorem, ultricies a auctor nec, auctor ut neque. Aenean varius, urna eget adipiscing feugiat, nunc ligula molestie massa, id accumsan turpis metus ac ante.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
</div>

<div class="target" id="id3">
  <p>Pellentesque quis tortor vitae elit cursus vulputate et vel dui. Nunc commodo pretium arcu in ultricies. Nunc vel velit enim, et tincidunt leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
</div>

<div class="target" id="id4">
  <p>Quisque eget tempor sapien. Cras convallis tempor orci pulvinar scelerisque. Nullam et erat eu nibh sollicitudin congue sit amet id diam. Sed in lectus ut augue euismod porta. Quisque non lacus odio. Nunc ornare adipiscing egestas.</p>
</div>

<div class="target default-target" id="id1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tempus, felis at varius eleifend, neque orci porta magna, consequat aliquam ligula velit quis erat. Aenean porttitor pellentesque risus, eu tincidunt ipsum blandit in.</p>
</div>
```

Но согласитесь, данная реализация выглядеть не очень красиво. Так что лучше воспользоваться *javascript*, что бы было меньше мороки и костылей